# How to create a parental control app in android

Tags: android, security

I want to create an android application which similar to the Norton Symantec

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.symantec.familysafety&hl=en

Is there any particular library in android to develop those type of apps, Seems that those apps have access to the internal functions of OS.

Thanks

Comment: Do you made ​​this app? I need to do one like this.

Comment: did u get solution?

Comment: u can use android work profile concept for this , or else can use customized launcher